# Using Tweenjs in setInterval to give an effect every time the properties of an image change

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs, tween.js

I am trying to create an effect that resembles camera flashes in a stadium. So I am using Tween in order to change the alpha of image. Each flash is expected to pop up and fade away within 500 milliseconds.
When I use use Tween outside the setInterval function, it works perfectly fine. But when I use it inside, the effect can't be seen. The image simply pops up and disappears. What can I do to get the desired effect? Here is my code.

```
var flash = new createjs.Bitmap('flash.png');
flash.image.onload = function (){
    flash.image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    flash.scaleX = flash.scaleY = 150/flash.image.width;
    flash.alpha = -1;
    stage.update();
}

setInterval(function (){
    flash.x = Math.floor(1281 * Math.random());
    flash.y = Math.floor(150 * Math.random() + 50);
    flash.alpha = 1;
    createjs.Tween.get(flash).to({alpha : -1}, 500);
    stage.update();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Are you updating the stage other than in your interval? If not, then it won't draw during the tween, just ever second. You should update the stage on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do just the same without setInterval at all
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script>
var stage;
var flash;

function init() 
{
    stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);  //set some FPS
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage); //set autiomatic refresh

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "flash.png";
    image.onload = handleImageLoad;
}

function handleImageLoad(e) 
{
    var image = event.target;
    flash = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    flash.image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    flash.scaleX = flash.scaleY = 150/flash.image.width;
    flash.alpha=0;
    stage.addChild(flash);
    someAnim();     
}

function someAnim()
{
     var newX= Math.floor(1281 * Math.random());
     var newY=Math.floor(150 * Math.random());
     flash.alpha=1;
     createjs.Tween.get(flash).to({x:newX,y:newY}).to({alpha : 0}, 500).wait(1000).call(someAnim); //let's go without setInterval, but recursion

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1281" height="150"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```